# How can I use two SEDE (SQL) queries as the inputs for a third query?

Tags: sql

This may seem like a Meta question at first, but it's actually about SQL.

I am curious about how many and which posts on Stack Overflow are both upvoted and downvoted. I tried to put together a [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query to find out, but couldn't get it to work.

I wrote the following subquery to find posts with a certain number of upvotes:

```
SELECT PostId as [Post Link], COUNT(v.PostId) AS 'Upvote count'
FROM Votes v
INNER JOIN Posts p
ON p.Id=v.PostId
WHERE PostTypeId = 1
  AND VoteTypeId = 2
GROUP BY v.PostId
HAVING COUNT(v.PostId) > 5
```

I'm using a similar one for downvotes.

What I don't know is how to write a query that returns only those posts that appear in the results of both subqueries. All of my attempts have been syntactically incorrect. Is there a term for what I'm trying to do that I can pop into Google? Maybe a special operator or keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to pull the answers that have a specific number of upvotes as well as a specific number of downvotes, then please try the following:

```
SELECT
  PostId as [Post Link],
  COUNT(CASE VoteTypeId WHEN 2 THEN v.PostId END) AS 'Upvote count',
  COUNT(CASE VoteTypeId WHEN 3 THEN v.PostId END) AS 'Downvote count'
FROM Votes v
INNER JOIN Posts p
ON p.Id=v.PostId
WHERE PostTypeId = 1
  AND VoteTypeId IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY v.PostId
HAVING COUNT(CASE VoteTypeId WHEN 2 THEN v.PostId END) > 150
   AND COUNT(CASE VoteTypeId WHEN 3 THEN v.PostId END) > 10
```

This will select you those answers that have more than 150 upvotes and more than 10 downvotes at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, found at the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/87/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site):

```
set nocount on 

declare @VoteStats table (PostId int, up int, down int) 

insert @VoteStats
select
    PostId, 
    up = sum(case when VoteTypeId = 2 then 1 else 0 end), 
    down = sum(case when VoteTypeId = 3 then 1 else 0 end)
from Votes
where VoteTypeId in (2,3)
group by PostId

set nocount off

select top 100 p.id as [Post Link] , up, down from @VoteStats 
join Posts p on PostId = p.Id
where down > (up * 0.5) and p.CommunityOwnedDate is null and p.ClosedDate is null
order by up desc
```